# PHP will not render in browers

Tags: php, apache

The followind code will not render on Firefox or Safari (OS X & MAMP) I have googled all afternoon but am new to web programming and I am more confused than when I started.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Examples</h1>

    <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>

    <br />

</body>
```

In Safari it displays the above code and Firefox asks what to do with it.

I suspect I need to set some options in Apache but definately need help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check out the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Nothing in the code looks wrong.  Create a info.php file and put in it only the following lines:

<?php phpinfo(); ?>

If that doesn't show the phpinfo file, that would mean PHP itself either isn't installed correctly or for some reason isn't running correctly.  Either way, MAMP would need re-installed or you'd need to rebuild the PHP installation.

On another note, you need to make sure the .php files are running out of the designated www folder of the MAMP installation.

Comment: Could a moderator/OP add the closing </html> tag back in - S/O won't let me make such a minor change.

Comment: One stupid question: did you copied this file in web root and do you access it from browser with http://localhost/example.php or similiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put these lines of code at the first line of you file, and check the error or warning you get.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Then tell me the result. I hope you can find out what is the problem.

Comment: +1 this too is a good solution to figuring out any issue, granted my last suggestion in the comment above in the OP is true.  Otherwise this option won't work.  Keep in mind that by the 'first line' Mohammad means AFTER the initial <?php declaration.  it won't work outside of the opening PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry I took so long to answer but had serious family problems. Fixed it by returning to my windows development environment

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure apache conf file. Check this http://www.petefreitag.com/item/516.cfm or this http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php

Comment: MAMP generally has PHP pre-configured in the httpd conf file.  So to jump straight to this conclusion is flawed fundamentally.  There are a plethora of reasons why the php isn't working, in fact if you look at my comment on the OP you'll see some of those options before jumping straight to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry I took so long to answer but had serious family problems. Fixed it by returning to my windows development environment